# Can't get Mesmotronic fullscreen ANE to enable immersive mode

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, ane

I've been trying to use Mesmotronic's full screen ANE (https://github.com/mesmotronic/air-fullscreen-ane) to hide the status bar and onscreen navigation buttons in my AIR app.

The app uses AIR version 17 and is running on a Nexus 5 with Android 5.1.

Number 4 in the following image is the effect that I'm trying to achieve: https://developer.android.com/images/training/imm-states.png

However, the best I can do is hide the status bar and replace the navigation bar shapes with gray dots; the navigation bar remains and is fully opaque. I've tried my best to follow the guidelines provided by Mesmotronic and have spent hours searching for solutions, but so far nothing has worked.

Here is the code for my app. Everything unrelated to the ANE has been stripped away:

```
import com.mesmotronic.ane.AndroidFullScreen;

public class Main extends Sprite 
{

    public function Main() 
    {
        this.addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage )
    }

    private function onAddedToStage( e:Event ):void 
    {
        removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage );

        this.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;

        if ( !AndroidFullScreen.immersiveMode() )
        {
            this.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I managed to solve this problem. It turned out the issue had nothing to do with the code but instead with how I had the ANE files set up in the project.